# Spark SQL cannot output the dataframe

Tags: python, hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I try running the following codes but I cannot get the result as the error message shown below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('hive').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

list = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(r"mypath/mydata.csv")
list.createOrReplaceTempView("mydata")
df = spark.sql("""select * from mydata""")
```

Error info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-31-61851d7298cc>", line 1, in <module>
    df = spark.sql("""select * from mydata""")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'
```

is anyone can help me figure out how to resolve this, I am using Spyder with Python 3.7.

Thank you!

Comment: try without `enableHiveSupport` `spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('hive').getOrCreate()`

Comment: It works, thank you @Shu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove enableHiveSuppprt if you are not using it

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('hive').getOrCreate()
```